# Download remote multi-module project from maven

Tags: java, maven, opensaml

I'm really new to Maven, i read about it the last 4 hours searching online for a solution, but i can't really figure out how to solve this problem:

I need to download this library, composed by many .jar 
https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/opensaml/

Everything inside dirs 3.1.1 in all opensaml-* dirs

This project it's based on Maven and there is a parent pom
https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/opensaml/opensaml-parent/3.1.1/opensaml-parent-3.1.1.pom
And every submodules have another pom file in all 3.1.1 directory with dependacies.
Ok the question it's quite easy, i want to download every jar on every directory of everymodule listed in parent pom for version 3.1.1 (If you look in the link the question become more easy).

Ok there is a way in maven to download everything specify a version and a link to repo/pom/whatever AND resolve dependacies ? (I think maven it's exactly for something like that)

Really thanks.

Comment: Hi, Have you checked this link: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/DEV/Setting+Up,+Configuring,+and+Using+Maven . This explains how to connect to their repo and install the jars with maven cordinates.

Comment: Hi thanks for answer. This page describe essentially how to deploy in maven as dev or how to build package.. It say "move to that directory and balblabla". Ok i haven't a copy of all repo, i want just download all that single jar with dependancies. It's not really this case, right? Or i need to wget the entire maven to "move to that directory?"

Answer (score 0):

Ok got OpenSaml 3.2.0 working right now. It's a bit tricky.
Basically you need to download all modules from svn repo, then build everything from *-parent directory. THEN you need to tell maven to download alla dependacy for you with mvn dependency:copy-dependencies (again inside the -parent). Then copy all jars from -opensaml-* and also from target/dependacy. THEN will work :)

For who it's interested i share i little bash to help you collecting all those jars. Just go inside java-opensaml dir after mvn dependency:copy-dependencies step and just:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in ./trunk/*/ ; do
#echo "$d"
k=$d'target/';
printf "Checking $k ...";
if [ -d "$k" ]; then
   printf "EXIST\n";
   find $k -iname "*SNAPSHOT.jar" -exec cp --remove-destination -v {} ./ \;
else
printf "fail\n";
fi

k=$d'target/dependency/';
printf "Checking $k ...";
if [ -d "$k" ]; then
   printf "EXIST\n";
   find $k -iname "*.jar" -exec cp --remove-destination -v {} ./ \;
else
printf "fail\n";
fi
printf "\n--\n";
done
```